# Simulating a full outer join in Java

Tags: java, join, outer-join

Let's say I have two arrays in Java and I wanted to preform a full outer join on them (returning a third array).

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Better index (= `HashMap`) the foreign-key column first, otherwise you're looking at O(n^2) time complexity of the join.

Comment: Left or right outer join? :-) Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup Seriously, what's the difference between a left and a right join here? It's like a trick question from an exam.

Comment: What does this question even mean in real life? What do you want the third array to contain? There are no details here with which to even approach answering.

Comment: Do an inner join, setting a flag on the rows in the respective left and right arrays to see whether they've matched anything in the other array. Then go over both arrays, and add a result row for each input row that hasn't matched anything. (This might not be the optimal way to do it, look at a database textbook to improve it.)

Comment: That said, the above assumes that it's a database-style join. The question as-is is too vague to answer well - we need some sort of example input, output, and what the actual rules are for turning the one into the other.

Comment: In a DBMS, we perform "joins" because the only relationship between one record and another record is, they have some value in common. (Perhaps `child.parent_id` equals `parent.id`, which means we have to join from `child` to `parent` to get details like `parent.name`.) But in Java, objects typically have references to each other, so no "joins" are needed. (We can just write `child.getParent().getName()`.) This isn't to say that there's *no* situation in which we'd want to do something join-like in Java, but it suggests that you might have some problems with your data-structure designs.

Comment: Full outer joins are used in database operations, with full data tables and multiple data fields for each entry. For example, in a business setting, you could execute a full outer join of two tables, one containing customers' addresses and the other containing billing information. It seems you want to create the *union* of the two arrays, in which case you should use [tieTYT's exceptional response below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14718662/1979005).

Comment: @MathSquared11235: Re: "It seems you want to create the *union* of the two arrays": What makes you say that?

Comment: The *union* is defined as "merging" two collections into one that keeps all the contents. An *outer join* is used in relational tables. Also, outer joins are used with *unordered* sets. Arrays are *ordered*. `Map`s or `Set`s work best for your situation.

Comment: @MathSquared11235: To clarify: I am not the OP. And I know exactly what unions and outer joins are. I just don't see any basis for your statement that (s)he really wants unions rather than outer joins. They're completely different concepts, and even if you're somehow confident that the OP can't really want a full outer join, how did you determine that what (s)he *does* want is a union? That seems rather arbitrary.

Comment: @MathSquared11235: . . . and come to think of it, unions are *also* specific to unordered collections. Even more so than joins, since with joins you can at least output your results in a lexicographic order based on the order of the inputs, whereas with unions there's no principled way to do that.

Comment: It seems the OP wants to merge the elements of the array. That's a full outer join in databases. It may not be union, granted, but it's not a full outer join. Besides, it's hard to merge two *ordered* collections -- the order of the elements is ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that [CollectionUtils from apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) will have everything you need and more.

Check out these methods and their description:

> **union**
>
> public static java.util.Collection union(java.util.Collection a,
>                                            java.util.Collection b)
>
> Returns a Collection containing the union of the given Collections.
>   The cardinality of each element in the returned Collection will be
>   equal to the maximum of the cardinality of that element in the two
>   given Collections.
>
> Parameters:
>
> a - the first collection, must not be null
>
> b - the second collection, must not be null Returns: the union of the two collections
>
> See Also: Collection.addAll(java.util.Collection)

This is probably what you need.  But to do left and right, I think what you'd use is this:

> **subtract**
>
> public static java.util.Collection subtract(java.util.Collection a,
>                                               java.util.Collection b)
>
> Returns a new Collection containing a - b. The cardinality of each
>   element e in the returned Collection will be the cardinality of e in a
>   minus the cardinality of e in b, or zero, whichever is greater.
>
> Parameters:
>
> a - the collection to subtract from, must not be null
>
> b - the collection to subtract, must not be null Returns: a new collection
>   with the results
>
> See Also: Collection.removeAll(java.util.Collection)